# How to group and count the number of people visits in particular year and months

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataset with personal data such as Date and Total Visits. I would build a graph with number of people visits in Particular Year or particular month. I'm using python pandas to accomplish this and my strategy but not able to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
#Get Month end date 
df['month_end'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x,freq='M').end_time.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

df_agg = df.groupby(['month_end'])['Total Visits'].sum().reset_index()
```

`df_agg` will have visits aggregated by month end date.

Use following to create bar plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
# Set Seaborn style
sns.set_style('darkgrid')


# Construct plot
sns.barplot(x = "month_end", y = "Total Visits", data = df_agg)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for this, this is actually I was looking for this. but one more question , How to see the trends in which year or month the number of people visits more or less in compare to other months

Comment: You can use libraries like matplotlib or seaborn to visualise the data. If you can share your dataframe in a reproducible format,I can create the visualisation.

Comment: Please check @SAL

Comment: @xoxo updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Make Columns for Month-year and Year, and use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)